# Guidelines for reading from Excel on Windows Azure Web Role

Tags: c#, excel, azure, azure-configuration

My requirement is to have the user upload a CSV or Excel file for import purposes on a web application running on Windows Azure. There is associated Excel column to Field Mapping requirement as well. My environment is C#, ASP.NET, SQL Server 2010.

I have a solution working with Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)). I am reasonably confident that this would not fly on Windows Azure given that the installer is putting registry entries on my computer + there would likely be security constraints on Azure.

Any guidelines/help on what would be an appropriate solution for the same on Windows Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Through startup scripts, you can modify the registry and run MSI's (as long as they're completely automated without user input). Remember that Windows Azure Web and Worker Roles are essentially Windows Server 2008 SP2 or R2, plus scaffold code called from either a startup script or the RoleEntryPoint implementation (including `OnStart()` and `Start()` ).

For more information about startup scripts, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was expecting these responses in my mailbox - that didn't happen. Thanks for the suggestion, would these be 64 bit libraries or 32 bit for Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Like David already explained in his answer you should use startup tasks to install the Microsoft Access Database Engine on your Web Role.

But if you think this installer might require administrator permissions (because of registry changes) you will need to specify this on your startup task. The startup task allows you to set the elevationContext to **elevated** to run your startup task as an administrator. You might need this to successfully install this package.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129545.aspx